# How to change programmatically a Contact from phone?

Tags: android, sql, database, contacts, android-contacts

This is my code:

```
FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation editXelionContact")

    val shouldResetXelionContact = xelionContact.isDefault
    var editResult = if (shouldResetXelionContact) RESET_FAILED else NOT_CREATED_FAILED

    if (xelionContact.isAnonymous) {
        FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation Do not edit XelionContact to anonymous: $xelionContact")
        return NOT_CREATED_ANONYMOUS
    }

    if (!xelionContact.isValid) {
        EXCEPTION_HANDLER.logAndReport("Test Contact Creation xelionContact not valid: name and/or number for XelionContact not set")
        FL.i(TAG,"Test Contact Creation xelionContact not valid: name and/or number for XelionContact not set")
        return editResult
    }

    if (!isCorrectNumberOfXelionContacts(1)) {
        EXCEPTION_HANDLER.logAndReport("Test Contact Creation Do not edit contact: invalid number of contacts (not 1)")
        FL.i(TAG,"Test Contact Creation Do not edit contact: invalid number of contacts (not 1)")
        return editResult
    }

    val existingXelionContact = existingXelionContact
    val shouldUpdateXelionContactConstantValues = !XelionContact.isLatestVersion
    if (shouldResetXelionContact && existingXelionContact.isDefault && !shouldUpdateXelionContactConstantValues) {
        FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation Do not reset the XelionContact if it is already default: $xelionContact")
        return NOT_RESET_ALREADY_DEFAULT
    }

    if (shouldResetXelionContact && !TELEPHONY_MANAGER.isPhoneIdle) {
        FL.d(TAG, "Test Contact Creation Don't reset the XelionContact to default while the phone is ringing or while calling.")
        resetXelionContactAfterCallEnded = true // To reset directly when call ends
        startXelionContactResetTimer() // To be sure reset will always be called (when CallLogChanged is unregistered reset won't be called anymore)
        return NOT_RESET_CALL_BUSY
    }

    FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation Edit contact. From: $existingXelionContact to: $xelionContact")

    val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()

    var builder = getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(SELECTION_NAME)
    builder.withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, xelionContact.readableName)
    ops.add(builder.build())

    if (!shouldResetXelionContact) { // If the XelionContact should be reset, then do not save the default phone number, but remember the last received phoneNumber
        builder = getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(SELECTION_PHONE_NUMBER_WORK)
        builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, xelionContact.phoneNumber!!.number)
        ops.add(builder.build())
        FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation Edit contact. If the XelionContact should be reset, then do not save the default phone number, but remember the last received phoneNumber")
    }

    if (shouldUpdateXelionContactConstantValues) {
        builder = getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(SELECTION_NOTE)
        builder.withValue(Note.NOTE, xelionContact.note)
        ops.add(builder.build())

        if (!existingXelionContact.hasPhoto()) {
            builder = getNewOperationBuilderForInsert(existingXelionContact.rawContactId, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        } else {
            builder = getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(SELECTION_PHOTO)
        }
        builder.withValue(Photo.PHOTO, xelionContact.photo)
        ops.add(builder.build())
    }

    try {
        FL.i("Test Contact Creation OPERATIONS ================")
        for (item in ops){
            FL.i("Test Contact Creation op: " + item.toString())
        }
        FL.i("Test Contact Creation OPERATIONS END")
        val result = contentResolver.applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops)
        dumpResults("editXelionContact", result)
        if (result.size > 0 && result.size == ops.size) {
            editResult = if (shouldResetXelionContact) RESET else CREATED
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        EXCEPTION_HANDLER.logAndReport(e)
        FL.i(TAG, "Test Contact Creation createXelionContact5: ${e.message}")
    }

    return editResult
```

LOG:

```
Test Contact Creation OPERATIONS ================
Test Contact Creation op: mType: 2, mUri: content://com.android.contacts/data, mSelection: 
account_type='com.xelion.android.account' AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/name', mExpectedCount: null, mYieldAllowed: false, mValues: data2=Alin Rosu via Xelion, mValuesBackReferences: null, mSelectionArgsBackReferences: null
I/Xelion7 dev: Test Contact Creation op: mType: 2, mUri: content://com.android.contacts/data, mSelection: account_type='com.xelion.android.account' AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2' AND data2='3', mExpectedCount: null, mYieldAllowed: false, mValues: data1=+31157630779, mValuesBackReferences: null, mSelectionArgsBackReferences: null
Test Contact Creation OPERATIONS END
V/_PHONE_CONTACT_ XelionContactManager: Test Contact editXelionContact ContentProviderResult: dumpResults
V/_PHONE_CONTACT_ XelionContactManager: Test Contact editXelionContact ContentProviderResult:ContentProviderResult(count=0)
V/_PHONE_CONTACT_ XelionContactManager: Test Contact editXelionContact ContentProviderResult:ContentProviderResult(count=0)
```

This works properly on all other phones except Samsung, Is samsung handling the Contacts somehow. different? What am I doing from? Also why is my ContentProviderResult found 0?

## EDIT:

Missing code:

```
 private fun getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(selectionName: String): ContentProviderOperation.Builder {
    val builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    builder.withSelection(getSelectionWithXelionContact(selectionName), null)
    return builder
}

  private fun getSelectionWithXelionContact(vararg extraSelections: String): String {
    val selection = StringBuilder(SELECTION_XELION_CONTACT)
    for (extraSelection in extraSelections) {
        StringFormatter.addOptionalDelimiterAndString(selection, " AND ", extraSelection)
    }
    return selection.toString()
}

   private val SELECTION_XELION_CONTACT = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + XelionAccountManager.XELION_ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'"

    private val SELECTION_NAME = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"

And I Do use the mime type and account type as Marmor assumes in his answer down.
```

NOTE: This works on most phones. Google Pixel 3, Huawei Mate 10 Pro, Vivo S1 Pro, One plus 6T are some that I tested personally. Just on Samsung it does not work.
NOTE2: I did fix this with a workaround, by deleting the contact when getting my push notification, this creating it again. For some reason on Samsung devices editing it, would not work, but worked fine with creating.
But would still like to find out why this happens. Is it cause Samsung phones maybe use a different "name" column. for display? Like "given_name" or "display_name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't post the code for: `getNewOperationBuilderForUpdateWithSelection(SELECTION_NAME)` but from the logs, i assume this selects on `account_type='com.xelion.android.account' AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/name'` which is missing some condition to specify which contact you're trying to edit.

This basically says update ALL the rows that are in account X with mimetype "name" and update them ALL to `Alin`. This might change many contacts, not just the one you're currently trying to edit.
You should probably add `AND CONTACT_ID = X` to your selection.